# Scipy optimizer to find the minimum error sum

Tags: python, dataframe, optimization, scipy

I've a table like this: 
[image]

My goal is using the Scipy optimize to find the right values of P1 and P2 so that my V3 is equal V1, with V3= P1+ P2. Im looking for a way to try different values of P1 and P2 to get the minimum possible value of abs(sum of error) = abs (V3-V1)

the solution using excel solver: 
[image]

but instead of having different values of P1 and P2 for each row I want a combination that gets V3 to be as close to V1 with condition of min error sum possible.

Comment: What is wrong with `P1 = V1; P2=0` ? Do you really need to solve an optimization problem for this ?

Comment: Because I want P1 and P2 be the same for in each row ... so thats why im looking to find the min sum of error

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to obtain. What do the variables mean? How are they related to each other? Are there any optimization conditions? What have you tried so far?

Comment: P1+P2=V3 what i'm looking to do is to find out what is the combination of those two values that can be put for each row so the sum of error abs(V3-V1) is the min possible. the only condition I have is that the p1 and p2 need to be the same in each row.

Comment: I don't understand how P1+P2=V3, it doesn't match your data. And what do V1 values depend on? Are they completely arbitrary or what?

Comment: yes they are completely arbitrary, the goal is with solver to find the right ones.

Comment: sorry I know its quite not clear im new to Scipy and don't know how to use if for dataframe form excel readers

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain what you said about P1+P2=V3, in your table none of the values match. Like in the first row, 1+2 is clearly not 0.9, right? That's the unclear part I'm talking about.

Comment: yes but as I said my goal it to find out what is the conbination of P1,P2 so the sum of them equal 0.9 or close but that same conbination of P1,P2 will be used also for second other rows ect ect ...

Comment: So is `V3=P1+P2` or not ? You just wrote the opposite !

Comment: the rule is that p1+p2=v3 but as its impossible if we used the same combination in each row to get V3 equal v1 so what im looking to do if find out whats the closet solution that can be use in each row so my V3 is as close as possible to V1 buy try different  P1,P2

Comment: Ok, let's try this way: we've established that the values in the V1 column are arbitrary and the ones in P1 and P2 are just you experimenting with random values. So, where do the values in the V3 column of the table come from?

Comment: from P1 and P2 as I said the goal is to get V3 as close as possible to V1 ... thats why using Scipy is maybe a solution to try different combinations P1,P2 so my V3s are as close as possible to V1s with same  P1,P2 in each row

Comment: I have edited my post mybe its clear now

Comment: And why is `V3` not equal to `P1 + P2` in your first table. Why would it be impossible ? I thought the definition of `V3` is that it is the sum of `P1` and `P2`.

Comment: they are btw -1 and 1

Comment: it's the rule that P1+P2=v3 but V3 can't equal V1 but can be close if we find thr right combination for P1 and P2 ... so each V3 equals approx V1 .. with that combo we can get the min error possible.

Comment: even an example of solution will help just to see how to use Scipy for this case might help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, I think I understand what you're trying to achieve, and you don't really need scipy to do it. 
For starters, you're not really interested in what the values of P1 and P2 are, because you really want to optimize only their sum V3, so actually any 2 numbers whose sum is the optimal V3 will do the job.
Now we're left to find V3. It's actually fairly easy to do, as the aforementioned optimal value will be one of the two numbers with only one significant decimal places closest to the mean. In code:

```
def find_minimum_error_sum(V1):
    error = lambda x: sum(abs(i-x) for i in V1)
    adjusted_mean = (sum(V1)*10//len(V1))/10
    if error(adjusted_mean) <= error(adjusted_mean+0.1):
        return adjusted_mean
    else:
        return adjusted_mean+0.1
```

Call the function on the array containing your V1 values and the V3 you're looking for will be returned. Then again, any 2 numbers whose sum is V3 can be your P1 and P2.
Be careful though: the function will work ONLY if every number in the array contains EXACTLY one significant decimal figure!

Edit: as Joseph Budin cleverly pointed out, you can just calculate the median of the array to find V3 straight out:

```
from statistics import median   
V3 = median([0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1])
```

And that's it.

Comment: Actually, the minimizer of the absolute error is the median of the `V1` values, so there is not even a need for this.

Comment: Yes, that's kind of what the function does, but of course it's supposed to work just as well with the median() function from the statistics module.

Comment: Or even the `np.median`, it's less exotic ;)

Comment: Let's just say that any function that, given a numerical array, returns its median, will perfectly work XD

Comment: but i'm still very curious to know how to the same thing in Scipy ... if you guys have time to show me i would be grateful ;)

Comment: How to compute a median in scipy ?

Comment: The solver .. I would love to know how to use it using dataframes read from excel to python

Comment: You sure can use it if you really want to, but for these kind of simple problems implementing it is not really worth it. I made an example [here](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwFET3OcVfJhBjY1FB6DW6KV2k2uCH/iQkEVovH1PFxWNmmGHClp/etaXY6AnSHcOmfMhI@J4BKfiYgdB9M@t1NzTqLBt1qbTy56@VU0WPzHaLoelhYL1BehE3U@LrAQVYHwEBHfRasBDRZf5/5VbCsI9rdVxmt@soBJTyAQ) if you want to check it out.